# Algolia-rails pagination with kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari, algolia

I am attempting to integrate my website(runs with RoR) with algolia search service.
can anyone help me how to paginate results(hits) with kaminari gem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project README has just been updated with some backend pagination examples:

Even if Algolia **highly recommends to perform all search (and therefore pagination) operations from your frontend using JavaScript**, the gem supports both [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) and [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) as pagination backend.

To use `:will_paginate`, specify the `:pagination_backend` as follow:

```
AlgoliaSearch.configuration = { application_id: 'YourApplicationID', api_key: 'YourAPIKey', pagination_backend: :will_paginate }
```

Then, as soon as you use the `search` method, the returning results will be a paginated set:

```
# in your controller
@results = MyModel.search('foo', hitsPerPage: 10)

# in your views
## if using will_paginate
<%= will_paginate @results %>

## if using kaminari
<%= paginate @results %>
```